# Deliver string as a page

Tags: django, django-views

I have in views.py a function that generates a string which is the content of an XML file. At the moment I am rendering it through a template:

```
def sitemap(request):
    sitemap_str = generate_sitemap_string_on_the_fly()
    return render(request, 'sitemap.html',
                  {'sitemap_str': sitemap_str},
                  content_type='text/xml')
```

An in the sitemap.html template, I simply have this line:

```
{{ sitemap_str|safe }}
```

Is there a better way to achieve this? My opinion is that using a template here is a bit of overshooting. Can I deliver the string without using a template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`render` is simply a shortcut to rendering a template and returning it wrapped in an HttpResponse. If you don't need the actual template part, simply create the HttpResponse directly:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
...
return HttpResponse(sitemap_str, content_type='text/xml')
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can simple return an HttpResponse without using templates.

```
return HttpResponse('<html><body>' + sitemap_str + '</body></html>')
```

or more simple

```
return HttpResponse(sitemap_str)
```